# Count unique subsets of size k with some S

Tags: c++, algorithm, subset-sum

> Team 7 faces a horrible foe. He can only be defeated with a special
>   quadruple combination attack of strength  ( 1 <=S <= 10^9 ).
>   Naruto, Sasuke, Sakura and Kakashi must attack simultaneously to
>   perform the combo. Each of them can choose from N ( 1 <= N <=1000 ) attacks, having strengths si each ( 0 <= i < N, 1 <= si <=10^9). The strengths of individual attacks add up to form the
>   strength of the combo.
>
> Is there a valid combination that they can use? Note that the same
>   attacks are available to all of them.
>
> You are required to write a function which takes input as follows – An
>   integer `N` as number of attacks, an integer vector `s[]` as the
>   strengths of `N` attacks and an integer `S` as the required strength
>   of the combo. Set the output variable to the number of distinct valid
>   combos.
>
> Two combinations are different if they differ in strength of at least
>   one attack used.

Input: `1 {1} 4`

Output: `1  ===>{1,1,1,1}`

Input: `2 {1,2} 5`

Output: `1 ===> {1,1,1,2}`

Below is my code its only passes 3 test cases out of 10. I don't know the test cases as it was some online code submission.

My Algorithm:
1) Create a hash with indexes as sum of pairs from input array and value as individual elements contributing to sum
2) Iterate over the hash and look if for i in hash there is k-i
3) Count above indexes and return count/2 as we are counting for both H(i) and H(k-i)

Please review the code and tell me what scenarios you think code will not produce right o/p.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<map>
#include<set>

const int noOfPalyers = 4;

int validCombo(int input1,int input2[],int input3)
{
    //Write code here
    int count = 0;
    std::vector<int> vec;
    int size =input1*noOfPalyers;
    for(int i = 0; i < input1; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < noOfPalyers;j++)
        {
            vec.push_back(input2[i]);
        }
    }

    std::vector< std::set< std::pair<int, int> > > vecHash;
    //vecHash.reserve(size*size);

    for(int i =0; i < (size*size); i++)
    {
        vecHash.push_back(std::set< std::pair<int, int> >());
    }

    for(int i =0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for(int j =1; j < size; j++)

        {
            int key = vec[i] + vec[j];
            if(vec[i]<= vec[j])
                vecHash[key].insert(std::make_pair(vec[i], vec[j]));
            else
                vecHash[key].insert(std::make_pair(vec[j], vec[i]));

        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < input3; i++)
    {
        if(vecHash[i].size() > 0 &&  i < input3)
        {
            if(vecHash[input3-i].size() > 0)
            {
                std::set< std::pair<int, int> >::iterator iter, iter2;
                for(iter=vecHash[i].begin(); iter!=vecHash[i].end();++iter)
                {

                    for(iter2=vecHash[input3-i].begin(); iter2!=vecHash[input3-i].end();++iter2)
                    {
                        std::cout<<(*iter).first<<","<< (*iter).second<<",";
                        std::cout<<(*iter2).first<<","<< (*iter2).second;
                        std::cout<<"\n";
                        count++;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }

    return (count ==1 ? count: count/2);

}

int  main()
{
    int i = 3;
    int arr[] = {1,2,3};
    int j = 7;
    int arr1[] ={1};
    std::cout <<"o/p == "  << validCombo(i, arr, j)<< "\n";
    std::cout <<"o/p == "  << validCombo(1, arr1, 4);


    //getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging the program with your own test cases? What were the results?

Comment: @Cameron i have run some test cases for them results are ok.. but not where i submitted only  3 cases passed

Comment: As an aside, I find your code hard to read, because none of the variable names hold any meaning. You may as well have named them all `a`, `b`, `c`, etc.

Comment: First of all, you have insane time and memory complexity. Last loop of your `validCombo` may have 10^9 * 10^6 steps. Also you definitely'll get `int` type overflow in the worst case because numbers will be about 10^9 and `int` type max value is ~4*10^9. And we haven't touched correctness of your solution. I'd recommend to start from the scratch again and rethink the problem you've faced

Comment: Also I'd recommend you to rethink variables naming :) Competitive programming, of course, force us to code fast. But short and clear variables naming helps you a lot every time your solution won't pass tests by first try when you have to debug and fix it.

Comment: @pkuderov My Algorithm: 1) Create a hash with indexes as sum of pairs from input array and value as individual elements contributing to sum 2) Iterate over the hash and look if for i in hash there is k-i 3) Count above indexes and return count/2 as we are counting for both H(i) and H(k-i). And i have used std::vector< std::set< std::pair<int, int> > > vecHash as hash.

Comment: Moderator, i request to remove hold from this post. I have solved the problem with the code above. So this post could be something like a problem and solution to it,  plz unhold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPD**. My God, now I've understood your comment :) and see that you tried to solve it the same way I wrote. Anyway, I hope you'll find some pieces of my explanation useful. First of all, you don't use hash functions (I know identity function is a hash func, but not the good one in our case).
 Also I didn't understand your `count` logic... I think you need to read `Two combinations are different if they differ in strength of at least one attack used.` part again and check your `count` logic.

There're just my first thoughts. Hope it could be helpful.

==================================

You know, this problem is about having particular sum of 4 numbers from the set. Let's imagine we have just 2 heroes (so 2 terms in our sum):

```
a + b = S,
```

where a, b are attack's strengths from set of N numbers (let's name it T). The number of different `a + b` sums is N^2. Simple calculating all of these sums and then searching those ones equal to S doesn't give us good solution. This problem can be solved with better complexity.

If we could find a fast function such that:

```
F(a) = F(S - b)
```

we would precalculate all F(S - b), then looped over all `a`'s and found which ones satisfy equality above. You mentioned hash. Hash functions can do this. We need such hash func to map all numbers from set `T` to range [0, N]. Because we just have no more than N different `a`'s. 
But we have a little problem here:

- `F(a) = F(S - b)` just means `a` can be equal to `S - b`. Fortunately, it's not a big problem,
- because the main power is: `F(a) != F(S - b)` means `a != S - b`.

Ok, as you see we have algorithm to solve `a + b = S` problem with amortized O(N) complexity. Sounds good and promising, right? :)

==================================

Now come back to your problem:

```
a + b + c + d = S
```

My idea to precalculate all `f(a + b)` with O(N^2) and store them like this (warning! just pseudocode):

```
vector<int> hash = new vector<int>(with size N)
foreach (a in T)
foreach (b in T)
{
    int x = OurHashFunc(a + b);  // a + b <= 2 * 10^9 so it never overflows int
    if (hash[x] == null)
        hash[x] = new vector<pair<int,int>>
    hash[x].push_back(new pair<int, int>(a, b));
}
```

We keep pairs (a,b) to be able to restore terms of initial sum. Then if our OurHashFunc is additive then transform our initial problem like this:

```
a + b + c + d = S             // apply hash func => 
f(a + b) + f(c + d) = f(S)    // rename => 
x + y = Z                     // wow, I bet I've already seen this equation ;)
```

Now 4-terms sum problem had reduced to 2-terms sum problem with an O(N^2) overhead. 
I think this reduction can be continued: 2^k-terms sum problem should have avg O(N^k) solution.

Comment: i used same algorithm, but different data structure. I used set inside my hash so that a+b=c  and b+a =c , so only one of these occur. And i have returned return (count ==1 ? count: count/2) because my count will be incremented for both H(a) and H(S-a), also when count ==1, i am not dividing it by 2 because of i have used set inside vector, so for this input 1 {1} 4 i would get count as 1.